# AutoIt + Citrix Simulation API - error 63

Tags: autoit, citrix

I am currently trying to integrate the Citrix Simulation API into an AutoIt script.

I am able to open a working connection and I can also successful do a logoff.
But while the session is open, I am not able to use important functions. For example I need to set the session to fullscreen using the FullScreenWindow() function.
The errorcode I get delivered is 63 - ICO_ERROR_NO_WINDOW  (no window found)

This is the code I am using to build the connection (shortened)

```
Local $citrix_object = ObjCreate("Citrix.ICAClient")
$citrix_object.Address = "hostname"
$citrix_object.Username = "user"
$citrix_object.SetProp("Password", "pass")
$citrix_object.Domain = "domain"

$citrix_object.Connect()
```

By executing this code I will logon to the citrix desktop and can use It. But I cant use functions like FullScreenWindow()

I read that a registry key needs to be set, so I have done that. But the problem still persists.
Key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client\CCM] "AllowSimulationAPI"=dword:00000001
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to set

```
$citrix_object.Launch = true;
```

If you use C++ it is trickier, then you have to do:

```
VARIANT_BOOL variantBoolTrue = -1;
pica->put_Launch(variantBoolTrue);
```